# Difference between one line and two line declaration?

Tags: c++, declaration

In C++, is there any difference between

```
Object o;
o = Object(); // calling the class constructor
```

and

```
Object o = Object(); // one-line declaration and construction
```

Is it the same thing in other language such as Java ? (aside from syntax)

Comment: aside from some similarities in syntax there is almost nothing the same in C++ and java

Comment: The first case default constructs an instance, then default constructs another and perform an assignment. In the second case, you only default construct a single instance and no assignment is performed.

Comment: Yes, Java adopts it's looks from C++. So there is much similarities.

Comment: So is there any performance difference between the two ?

Comment: @Jean-LucM. There can be, depending on how `Object` is implemented and whether copy assignments are cheap or expensive to perform.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: Please do **not** answer questions in the comments section.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, there is a difference.

In fact, there is no such thing as a "two-line declaration"; your terminology is all off. Let's have a look.

```
Object o;
o = Object();
```

Here you declared an object `o`, calling the *default constructor*. Then, on the next line, you created *another* object (this one without a name) also with the default constructor, then *assigned* it to `o`. Pretty wasteful all around.

```
Object o = Object();
```

Here you declared an object `o`, calling the *copy constructor* with another object (this one without a name). This one is called "copy initialisation", and is also pretty wasteful in this example, though a feature called "copy elision" may eliminate the redundancy for you.

What you want is this:

```
Object o;
```

This default-constructs an object named `o`; problem solved.

Comment: `Object o;` **defines** an object. `extern Object o;` **declares** an object.

Comment: @PeteBecker: Definitions are also declarations.

Comment: Declarations are not definitions. What matters here is that these are **definitions**, because that's where initializations are done.

Comment: @PeteBecker: I did not claim that declarations are definitions.

Answer (score -1):

In first case compiler generate one call of constructor and then second call of constructor for create second instance and use copy or more assignment operators. In second case compiler generate only one call of constructor.

Comment: even if you compile with optimizations, compiler has no right to believe you don't need first instance

Comment: _"In the second case, the compiler calls the Object default constructor one time to initialize o. There is no second object used at all."_ You are wrong. This is copy-initialisation. Modulo copy elision, there are two objects here.

Comment: @George: Because, as I explained in my previous comment, it was an "incorrection" edit, i.e. it was wrong.